# Generate a 128 length of hashed string c#

Tags: c#, hash

I am new to hashing the data, I got a requirement to Hash data to the length of 128.
Tried hashing using SHA256 and SHA512, which produces 44 and 88 lengths of hashed data. Is there any way to generate hashed data at a specified length?
I am trying to achieve using the below code.

```
var value = "Test";
using var sha256 = SHA256.Create();
byte[] privatekeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
var text =  Convert.ToBase64String(sha256.ComputeHash(privatekeyBytes));
```

I know it's a pretty basic question, any links to understand more on this will also help me.

Comment: what is your requirement ? You need byte array length 128 or string length 128.

Comment: Whether at 128 bytes or 128 Base64 characters, there is honestly no sensible application for a hash that large. Double check your *real* requirement -- maybe someone was talking about 128 *bits*, or else something concatenated with an HMAC. Don't just hash things at random to see if you get a particular length.

Comment: What "length" means is not even the main problem. Lets assume you want 128 byte output. Standard SHA256 outputs 32 bytes. What exactly stops you from hashing the input once with SHA256 and concatenating 4 copies of the result? Or even simplier: just fill missing bytes with zeros. Both certainly are valid hashing methods. In other words: what properties of the new hash you expect? Your "requirements" are very vague.

Comment: Question... why? SHA512 was largely ruled to be overkill. This: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18695/does-sha-1024-hash-exist provides some insight into alternative hashing methods.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to achieve. In some contexts, I keep insisting that `return 1` is a valid hash function. By and large, there are three applications for hashes:

- Quickly differentiate between data that is certainly different for better runtime performance. For that purpose, depending on your data something dumb like `return input.Length` can be perfectly sufficient.
- Evenly distribute data in a `HashSet` or similar, i.e., you primarily care that all available hashes are used roughly equally often. For that, and again depending on the type of data you are processing, it might suffice to take the first 128 bytes, XOR them with the next 128 bytes, XOR with the next 128 bytes and so on until the end of the input data.
- Cryptographically sign something. For that you should use one of the hashing algorithms designed for that purpose; they all produce a fixed number of bytes. If you find one that produces more than 128 bytes, it is perfectly fine to just truncate it to that length (at the loss of the additional security the extra bytes would have brought). As far as I can see, SHA512 is available in C# and should return a sufficiently long hash, that is, `SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(privatekeyBytes).First(128)`.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up bits and bytes. I know of no hashes that produce more than 128 bytes(1024 bits).

Comment: My bad. It really begs the question: What does OP need 128 bytes for? Unless they are working on a brand new super-secure encryption -- but then I guess they shouldn't pose that question on StackOverflow as if there were an easy answer.

Comment: P.S.: Fowler–Noll–Vo hash seems to support up to 1024 bits, but is apparently not implemented out of the box in C#. Also, it probably does not qualify as a secure cryptographic hashing algorithm.

Comment: For all we know OP has also confused bits and bytes. These days most questions on SO are [XY problems](https://xyproblem.info/), and particularly in crypto people will take some mistaken design idea 90% of the way and then ask something like "how to I make my hash output 128 bytes" in an attempt to get to 100%.